# Dot Net Core 3.1 Including package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore" doesn't recognize EntityFrameworkCore part

Tags: data-protection

I want to implement Dataprotection using PersistKeysToDbContext as it was shown in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I already installed the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore" NuGet package as suggested.

But, when I wanted to implement the next class :

```
class MyKeysContext : DbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
    {
        // A recommended constructor overload when using EF Core 
        // with dependency injection.
        public MyKeysContext(DbContextOptions<MyKeysContext> options) 
            : base(options) { }

        // This maps to the table that stores keys.
        public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; }
    }
```

I had to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore it is ok, I already include this part on the top of the class code.
The issue is the part EntityFrameworkCore appears with zigzag red color, which means that the DataProtection namespace doesn't include EntityFrameworkCore. 
It seems that "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore" package conflict with Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,
Actually I am using two projects with the same solution, One is the Web.Core and the Other is Web.Services

The class "MyKeysContext" was added to the Web.Services project and I was trying to install the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore" NuGet package on the Web.Core project.
So, I realized that I was trying to install the package in the wrong project.
I just installed the package again on Web.Services project and it worked.